# while loop doesnt work, waits for an entry

Tags: python, python-3.x

this is my code:

```
def usagePerUserApi():
    a = True
    while a==True:
        url = 
        resp = requests.get(url, headers=headers, verify=False)
        data = json.loads(resp.content)
        code = resp.status_code
        Verbindungscheck.ausgabeVerbindungsCode(code)
        print("---")
        head = ....
        table = []
        for item in (data['data']):
            if item['un'] == tecNo:
                table.append([
                    ....
                ])

        time.sleep(300)
        b = int(input("To go back, entry 0:"))
        if b == 0:
            a = False
```

I want him to automatically update the loop every 5 minutes until the user enters a 0.
In my code it executes the loop once, and then waits until the user has made an entry. If the user does not make an entry, nothing happens and it continues to wait.

Comment: As a side note, you should not use `while a==True` but `while a`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The input function is blocking. Meaning that unless something is written in the standard input, it will keep the process blocked.

If you want to execute processes in the background while waiting for user input, you may use a different thread. As an example, there is [the threading library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html)

Source: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input